# 無限に2バイトを返すio.Readerからio.CopyNで奇数バイトをコピーするとpanic

Tags: go

以下のように無限に2バイトを返し続ける`io.Reader`を実装して、そこから奇数バイト（例では5バイト）を`io.CopyN`でコピーしようとするとpanicを起こしました。偶数バイトをコピーする場合には起きません。なぜでしょうか？

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
)

type stream int

func (s *stream) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    p[0] = byte('a')
    p[1] = byte('b')
    return 2, nil
}

func main() {
    io.CopyN(os.Stdout, new(stream), 5)
    // panic: runtime error: index out of range
}
```

環境：go version go1.10.3 windows/386

Comment: io.CopyN() では、内部で [LimitedReader.Read()](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/io/io.go#L441) が実行されます。Read() メソッドに渡される byte 型のスライス `p` の長さが最後の段階で 1 となって、`p[1]` にアクセスして panic が発生しています。ですので、[こんな感じ](https://play.golang.org/p/vInMda8G39F)に書き直す必要があります。

Comment: @metropolis 頂いたリンク先を見て原因が理解できました。ありがとうございます。長さの分からない `p` に対して `p[1]=` などと、初歩的なミスでした。頂いたコードは[このように](https://play.golang.org/p/GUsKmBNie9b)書いてもよいかと考えましたが、そもそも2バイト全てを返せなかった場合にはどうするか（捨てるのか、次のreadに持ち越すのか、など）という仕様の検討が不足していたことにも気付きました。それと、コピーするバイト数を32KB以上にすると奇数バイトでもpanicにならず、その点も実は不思議だったのですが、LimitedReader.Read()の[この判定](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/io/io.go#L445)に入らなくなることが理由だったことも分かりました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

自己回答です。（metropolisさんのコメントから）

`io.CopyN` 関数は、受け取った `io.Reader` を `io.LimitedReader` でラップしてから `io.Copy` に渡してコピーしています。

今回の例ですと、`io.LimitedReader` はラップした `io.Reader` から、以下のバッファサイズでreadします。

- １回目のread：5バイト（そして2バイト読み込む）
- ２回目のread：3バイト（そして2バイト読み込む）
- ３回目のread：1バイト

３回目のreadではバッファサイズは1バイトであるため、`p[1]` にアクセスしようとして `index out of range` が発生します。

正しくは、受け取ったバッファ `p` が必要なサイズを満たしているかどうかをチェックするべきです。